# Does Ubuntu 22.04 require a UEFI instead of a BIOS?

Tags: boot, uefi, bios, 22.04

I am trying to install 22.04 on a couple of old machines. They each have a BIOS instead of a UEFI. Neither can boot from the USB stick I created. At boot, one of them displays the message "Operation System not found". The other says, "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key". A USB stick that contains Ubuntu 20.04.4 boots on the same machines with no problems. Does Ubuntu 22.04 officially require a UEFI, or is this a bug?

The machines in question:

- Dell XPS L702X laptop, Intel Core i5-2450M CPU, 8 GB of memory
- Home-built computer with Asus P5Q-EM motherboard, Intel Core 2 Duo CPU, 4 GB of memory

Comment: @jim what operating system you are creating usb drive on? Thanks.

Comment: @Jags, I created the USB drives on a Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS machine.

Comment: Try creating usb drive using `mkusb` utility from this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~mkusb/+archive/ubuntu/unstable Once you install `mkusb` on your `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS machine`, prepare the flash drive using `mkusb > dus` option. Let us know if that works for you or you need help with mkusb. Thanks.

Comment: Did you verify the downloaded ISO before flashing? You need to make sure that checksums match to verify the integrity of the download. Once you do that, you can flash the ISO to a USB flash drive. The [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop) recommends etcher for flashing the ISO. USB installation media flashed with etcher can boot as UEFI or Legacy BIOS.

Comment: @Nmath, I verified the checksum of the ISO. I have written the ISO to two different flash drives with Startup Disk Creator.

Comment: @jim Many non-UEFI BIOS machines fails to boot Ubuntu since `Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy`. For some of these machines, `mkusb` or `Rufus` (To prepare usb drive on Windows PC) are the only options to boot Ubuntu 20.10 onwards. Here's a bug report detailing the issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1899308

Comment: @Jags thanks for that link to the bug report. That answered a lot of questions I had.

Comment: The Dell laptop is UEFI so it should be installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, I think that the laptop uses BIOS because the main BIOS setup screen shows "BIOS Version  A17".

Comment: It is set to "BIOS"/Legacy mode as all consumer grade computers of the same vintage that shipped with preinstalled Windows 7. It is UEFI regardless and should be installed in UEFI mode. Actually there's a very recent firmware update that you should install, published in 2020 (latest Windows drivers published in 2013).

Comment: @ChanganAuto, What do you mean by "should be installed in UEFI mode"? There is no legacy/BIOS/UEFI mode control in the BIOS setup options, and it is my understanding that the USB stick made by Startup Disk Creator should work with a UEFI machine.

Comment: Very likely there is a CSM setting (CSM = Legacy), that it says "BIOS version ..." is irrelevant, "BIOS" is (wrongly) used to this day, a decade after UEFI became mainstream and ubiquitous, in reference to UEFI. And again, you should update "BIOS" to the latest version available. Yes, any installation media produced with any tool using `dd` should boot either way but the aforementioned bug likely affects both old BIOS machines and some early (and often "broken") UEFI implementations. Also as above, `mkusb` should work around it.

Comment: @Jim, Did you try with mkusb, as suggested by Jags? In this case please notice that Cloning (making a live-only drive) will do the same as the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator. So you should **use mkusb-dus (version 12.7.5) from the unstable PPA and make a *persistent* live drive**. It might work for you, because it has a different boot structure (another grub version) than a cloned drive from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. See [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=57&p=14091412#post14091412).

Comment: since *buntu 20.10 this uefi part is annoying. Even the live system is booted up in bios mode the installer wants to create an efi filesystem and demands gpt.

Comment: @sudodus, I installed 12.7.5 and selected "persisent live". In the msdos/upefi/d-n-i window, I clicked "use defaults". For the amount of space, I clicked "use default". When I click "go", it appears that nothing happens. mkusb-dus immediately goes back to the "clone, live, persistent, extracting" menu. The last messages in the console are "Usage: sudo -H /usr/sbin/dus-persistent", then "p_clean:".

Comment: hi @jim I've just posted an answer, as it was too long to describe in a comment. There are few ways to create a bootable USB drive with `mkusb / dus`. I've posted an answer with option-1, and writing up another. Let us know if you run into any issues. Thanks.

Comment: @jim, I think you missed at "Select Go (radio button) on the window, and then click Go (bottom-right corner of the window) button." This is well described by Jags in the full answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy, many non-UEFI, BIOS-only machines fails to boot Ubuntu ISO. In order to create a bootable USB drive for these machines, you will need to use `mkusb > dus`, `iso2usb > dus`, or `Rufus` utilities.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1899308

https://bugs.launchpad.net/mkusb/+bug/1971119

**Creating bootable USB drive:**

**On Windows machine:**

As described on this Ubuntu.com's [iso2usb page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb), [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) is the officially recommended tool to install Ubuntu from Windows.

1, Download `Rufus` utility from this page: https://rufus.ie/en/

2, Right-click on `rufus-3.18.exe` (or later version), and click on `Run as administrator`

3, Now on the Rufus window:

3.1, Device: Make sure it's a correct USB drive, eg: `USB Drive [64 GB]`

3.2, Boot selection: Click `Select`, and locate Ubuntu iso, eg: `ubuntu-mate-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso` (or any other Ubuntu flavor)

3.3, Partition scheme: `MBR`

3.4, Target system: `BIOS or UEFI`

3.5, Leave rest of the options as it is, and click `Start`

4, ISOHybrid image detected: Select (click radio-button) `Write in ISO Image Mode (Recommended)`

5, Warning: All data on device `USB Drive [64 GB]` will be destroyed.

Make sure you have selected the correct USB drive, and click `OK`

6, This will take about 5-7 minutes to complete. Once done, close Rufus window and safely remove the USB drive.

7, Connect newly created bootable USB drive to target machine, reboot the machine, and select USB drive from BIOS' boot menu.

8, When you see the `Grub menu`, select `Try or Install Ubuntu MATE` to boot the machine from USB drive.

**On Ubuntu machine:**

**Install mkusb:**

To create a bootable USB drive for non-UEFI machines, add this `mkusb` [unstable ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Emkusb/+archive/ubuntu/unstable) to install the latest version `12.7.5-1ubuntu1`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb
```

**Create bootable USB drive:**

To be used on non-UEFI machines, you can create bootable USB drive for Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy in few different ways.

**Option-1:** `mkusb > dus`:

1, Open `mkusb` from start menu

2, Click `Yes` on `Run mkusb version dus?`

3, Enter password

4, Click `OK` on `Do USB Stuff; Welcome and notice about overwriting` window

5, Select `Install (make a boot device)` and click `OK`

6, Select `Persistent-live - only Debian and Ubuntu` and clcik `OK`

7, A new window will open; locate and select source iso;

8, Most Important: Select target device: sdx (under device) | Kingston_Ultimate (target name/model) | 58.6G (size) and Click `OK`

9, Confirm: `'/dev/sdx' drive size = 63 GB. Please check again!`
`Do you really want to overwrite this target device?`

Make sure the target device is the correct USB drive, and click `Yes`

10, Persistent live drive settings: Select `msdos` and `upefi` and click `OK`

11, Select space for persistent (percent): 40% (You can select different number) and click `OK`

12, Final checkpoint, go ahead? Make sure that: (a) Source ISO is the correct one (b) Target device is the correct USB drive `/dev/sdx` (c) Correct device name is listed there: Kingston_Ultimate

Select `Go` (radio button) on the window, and then click `Go` (bottom-right corner of the window) button.

12, It would take about 5-7 minutes to create the bootable USB drive from this point.

13, When the `mkusb` completes the installation, you will see a `Done` window:

```
`Work done with /dev/sdx`

`The target device is ready to use.
'/path/to/iso/ubuntu-mate-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso was installed`

Click `OK` > `Quit` > `Quit` (again) > `Press Enter to finish`.
```

14, Connect newly created bootable USB drive to target machine, reboot the machine, and select USB drive from BIOS' boot menu.

15, When you see the `Grub menu`, select Ubuntu persistent-live (or similar) to boot the machine from USB drive.

**Option-2:** `iso2usb > dus`:

Now some of the non-UEFI machines may not boot `Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy` with `mkusb > dus` option described above, as they may need `msdos` partition table. Process for these machines:

1, As described and linked on this `Ubuntu.com's` [iso2usb page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/isoboot), get `grub boot template` file:

https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/dd_grub-boot-template-for-uefi-n-bios_msdos.img.xz

2, Using `GParted`, format a flash drive to FAT32, and note down it's partition name, e.g: sdx

3, Now use `dus` to install/extract earlier downloaded `img.xz` file to usb flash drive:

Open a terminal where you've downloaded the `img.xz` file, and run

```
dus dd_grub-boot-template-for-uefi-n-bios_msdos.img.xz
```

4, Enter password.

5, Click `OK` on `Do USB Stuff` window that say:

```
Welcome and Notice about Overwriting
The target device will be completely overwritten
```

6, Most Important:

Select target device: sdx (under device) | Kingston_Ultimate (target name/model) | 58.6G (size) and Click `OK`

7, Confirm: `Please check again`

`'/dev/sdx' drive size = 63 GB. Please check again!`
`Do you really want to overwrite this target device?`

Make sure the target device is the correct USB drive, and click `Yes`

8, Final checkpoint, go ahead? Make sure that:

(a) Source file is the correct one: `dd_grub-boot-template-for-uefi-n-bios_msdos.img.xz`

(b) Target device is the correct USB drive `/dev/sdx`

(c) Correct device name/model is listed there: `Kingston_Ultimate`

Select `Go` (radio button) on the window, and then click `Go` (bottom-right corner of the window) button.

9, It would take about 5-7 minutes to complete the process of `img.xz` extraction onto the USB drive.

10, Check the result (scroll if possible), press Enter to finish:

```
The target device is unmounted and you can unplug it.
The system might not see the current partition table of the
target device unless you re-plug it.
```

Click `OK`

11, Remove and replug the usb drive.

12, Copy Ubuntu MATE 22.04 Jammy (or any other flavor of Ubuntu) iso into `ISODEVICE` partition of the USB drive.

13, Once the iso is copied, rename ths iso to: `ubuntu.iso`

14, Connect newly created bootable USB drive to target machine, reboot the machine, and select USB drive from BIOS' boot menu.

15, When you see the `Grub menu`, select `Ubuntu.iso` to boot the machine from USB drive.

Comment: +1 for these detailed instructions :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Mkusb made a drive that booted on the Asus motherboard, but not the Dell laptop. Rufus made a drive that booted on both machines.

Comment: @ Jags and @ Jim,  [This link to my thread at the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&p=14095034#post14095034) introduces a new version of mkusb, with an early version of the script **`dus-iso2usb`**. I think and hope that it will be able to solve problems, where it is difficult to boot cloned live (and persistent live) drives with new Ubuntu versions. Please test it and let me know if/how it works with your computer.

Comment: @sudodus many thanks and will report back to you in a day.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed instructions. On an old Toshiba A660, i5/4Gb none of the method worked with Ubuntu 22. mkusb results in 'failed to boot from USB...' (as all others - Balena, WoeUSB), Rufus-created USB went a bit farther but still GRUB error 'unknown filesystem, emergency mode'. 
Ubunto 18 boots w/o any problems with any of above software.
Probably giving up on new distros, that's way too much fuss, and honestly a bit sad, there is no reason new distros shouldn't support a bit older systems (after all it's not a 1980-made PC).

Answer (score 0):

Came across when I search for making Lubuntu 22.04 persistence usb. If you look for just having the iso bootable. Use ventoy. Kudos for Jags's detailed answer though. Tested ventoy to boot lubuntu 22.04 on my acer one happy. Just unzipp it and run the .exe (Windows) or the .sh (Linux). Then just copy the iso to "ventoy" labelled disk.
Ps. Sorry for too lazy for more thorough answer. And pardon my English.
Just sharing. Booted lubuntu 22.04 and tried to install it for dual booting with already installed win11. Lubuntu when partitioning, lubuntu insisted to reformat whole disk as gpt and promised me that it'll create 8mb bios bootable Partition. Which then I cancelled it.