# Cannot install 22.04 on older laptop. Operating System Not found

Tags: boot, bootloader, 22.04

Install goes fine but no matter what option I chose after install it says "Operating System Not Found".

Hardware is a XPS 13 L321X Intel Core i5-2467M (10 plus years old) running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Had the same error when trying to boot from USB after following the instructions for creating the USB boot drive in the end got it working on Windows using Rufus...

Had about 10 install attempts never seems to find any OS on the SSD HD when finished.

I am guess there is some problem with legacy booting or something... any ideas?

This computer was working with the previous LTS 20.04

Comment: Can you provide more information about your hardware? What CPU model do you have? Please follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). By following the tutorial this will help you provide details and context if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: hi @andrewt `in the end got it working on Windows using Rufus...` It sounds like your issue has been resolved using `Rufus on Windows`. If you want to create bootable USB drive on Ubuntu, please go through my answer from 2 days ago: https://askubuntu.com/a/1407229/928088 Thanks.

Comment: @Jags my issue is installing it on my PC, I only mentioned the issues getting a USB drive to work in case it was relevent to the problem.. I will check you article anyway as it seems crazy that Windows is needed to creating Ubuntu boot drives

Comment: @Nmath XPS 13 L321X Intel Core i5-2467M

Comment: I didn't use Etcher will recreate USB disk, is startup disk Creator no longer supported?

Comment: It is, but since we are troubleshooting, it is best if you follow the prescribed directions in case you may be doing something incorrectly. Before flashing, it is also a good idea to [verify the downloaded ISO](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu)

Comment: @andrewt Could you please edit your post and describe the issues you are having while trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy. Also, the booting issues you've had, could be related to non-UEFI, BIOS-only machines. Thanks.

Comment: @Jags install works fine as per my description but when completed it cannot boot from the drive, will edit to make more obvious

Comment: @Nmath tried using your link which uses Etcher to burn the ISO, this made it worse as it can no longer boot from USB either now. I will use Windows to create another from Rufus.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what type of installation you use. Is it a UEFI or a Legacy install?

Most old laptops do have support for both UEFI and Legacy OSes, just make sure to use the correct one.

Try disabling CSM support in your BIOS settings, which is the thing that allows Legacy on UEFI BIOSes.

And before the installation of Ubuntu, make sure to use a GPT drive instead of an MSDOS layout. You can do that in GParted, which is on the live media.

Legacy is well, Legacy. It's outdated at this point and useless unless you're installing an old Linux distro or copy of Windows that doesn't have UEFI support in its kernel.

Comment: Quick comment: to do a new partition table using GParted, select your drive (making sure its the right one so you don't nuke important information or the installation media), select **Device** in the top panel, then select **Create Partition Table**, then just pick GPT, as the default is MSDOS, which is for Legacy BIOSes.

Comment: Used Gparted to grate a GPT partition table and tried the install again but same problem.

Comment: BIOS has no options for UFI CSM or anything like it and there is no BIOS update available from DELL

Comment: Hmm. Well, I have no idea either then. Try perhaps doing an MSDOS partition layout and then install Ubuntu?